# NSURLErrorDomain error -1012 when checking for software updates

Tags: macos, software-update, dns, beta, ventura

There is a new MacOS Ventura update that was recently released. When I check for updates, I get the following error.

[image: error]

I used the commands `sudo softwareupdate --dump-state` and then `open /System/Applications/TextEdit.app /var/log/install.log` to see the log output. I also used the command `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to reset the DNS cache. This also did not fix the problem, even changing DNS server settings to Google or Quad9.

Did anyone else get the error `NSURLErrorDomain error -1012 when checking for software updates` before? How did you fix the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the latest macOS Ventura installer and run
"Install macOS Ventura.app" manually, it will upgrade your OS.

After that I'd also recommend removing your mac from the Apple Developer Seed Program:
[image]